# how to add new key with items as value to a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have this nested dictionary:

```
cities = {
'new york city':{
    'country':'united states',
    'population': '8 million',
    'attraction':'statue of liberty'},
}
```

... and I am trying to add a new key and a few key-value pair as items to the nested dict:

```
cities['white plains'] = {'white plains'}
cities['white plains'] = {'country': 'united states'}
cities['white plains'] = {'population':'60 thousand'}
cities['white plains'] = {'attraction': 'kensico dam'}
```

... and its not working. (I am using 3.5)

Comment: How is it "not working"? What is the desired output? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Not all of those things are dictionaries - `{ 'white plains' }` is a set.  You should reread the docs and then post what you mean by "not working"

Comment: here is the rest of my code:                                                                             for city, city_info in cities.items():
    print('\n City name : ' + city.title())
    print('Country : ' + city_info['country'].title())
    print('City population : ' + city_info['population'])
    print('Attraction: ' + city_info['attraction'].title())                                                   and here is the error :                                                                       print('Country : ' + city_info['country'].title())
KeyError: 'country'

Comment: Why would you think anyone would want to read a code dump like that in your comment? **Edit your question.**

Comment: I did edited. I tried to line it up. It looked ok when I sent it.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing over data already stored under your key each time, losing previous data if any

(plus the first statement `cities['white plains'] = {'white plains'}` is incorrect: you're associating key with a `set` containing the key value, okay wasn't a problem since you overwrote it just after :))

You need to do:

```
cities['white plains']['attraction'] = 'kensico dam'
```

or

```
cities['white plains'].update({'attraction':'kensico dam'})
```

the latter having the advantage of being able to add more than 1 key at once.

Note: if the key does not exist and you want this to work, you have to use `collections.defaultdict` by declaring `cities` like this:

```
import collections
cities = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

so when the key doesn't exist, a dictionary is created instead of getting `KeyError` exception.

Comment: `update` parameter should be a dict, not a set

Comment: I think you should put it another way. Not _"You're creating another dictionary each time, losing previous data."_ but " but e.g _"You're rewriting your value for key = `'white plains'` each time, etc"_

Comment: @aluriak: right!! edited. Got caught at over-answering with wrong code. Thx.

Comment: @vishes_shell taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
cities['white plains'] = {
  'country': 'united states',
  'population':'60 thousand',
  'attraction': 'kensico dam'
}
```

Comment: perfect!!! Thank you very much